# Cookie.HTTPOnly in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

How to set all the cookie variables in a page to HTTPOnly in ASP?

Answer (score 11):

I'm afraid using the Response.Cookies collection will not work when setting HttpOnly (it's been driving me slowly mad!).
As vbscript (well at least on the server i'm testing on) will character encode the semicolon.

Instead, add the header manually yourself, for example:

```
Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", "YourCookieName=YourCookieValue; path=/; HttpOnly"
```

There is a similar post on stackoverflow called: [How exactly do you configure httpOnly Cookies in ASP Classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296/how-exactly-do-you-configure-httponly-cookies-in-asp-classic)

Comment: YES! This does work. Pity it is not the accepted answer because I followed that one and wasted a lot of time!

Comment: Thank you Alex - some interesting cloud modernization projects are digging up interesting artifacts!

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft nice to bump into you in the virtual world :-) Good'ol vbscript!

Answer (score 2):

I compiled the Microsoft's ISAPI filter example (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972826). This solved my problem.

The ISAPI DLL is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/e5mq749acms0rhx/HTTPOnly.dll?dl=0

Feel free to download.

Comment: Link is dead. Is any other alternative way to download the dll file?

Comment: Thanks. Does this set secure and httponly flags?
What's the correct way to install it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", ""&CStr(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_COOKIE"))&";path=/;HttpOnly"&""
```

Answer (score -1):

Ancient question, but I had to figure it out for a legacy app myself.

Classic ASP's `Response.Cookies` collection just won't do the trick for adding the `HttpOnly` tag. You need to use

```
Response.AddHeader("Set-Cookie", useful_value)
```

to get this to work.  If you try to set the Path attribute of an item in the `Response.Cookies` collection like this

```
Response.Cookies["stupid"].Path = "/; HttpOnly"
```

it helpfully URLEncodes the semicolon, thus corrupting the path.

So, I banged out a couple of classic asp functions for the purpose, offered here in solidarity with everybody living with classic asp.

```
' given a Date item, return the text string suitable for a cookie's expires= field.
' For example: Tue, 02-Aug-2016 18:57:00 GMT
function RFC6265Date (inputDate)
  ' (we are on EST, Z-5, so offset the time. Classic ASP, no timezone support)
  dim date: date = DateAdd("h",5,inputDate)
  dim v : v = WeekdayName(Weekday(date),true) & ", "
  v = v & Right("00" & Day(date), 2) & "-" 
  v = v & MonthName(Month(date),true) & "-" & Year(date) & " "
  v = v & FormatDateTime(date,4) & ":00 GMT"

  RFC6265Date = v

end function

' make cookie header value including various security items
function RFC6265CookieValue(name, val, inputDate, domain)
'name=tok=val&tok=val&tok=val; domain=.glance.net; expires=Tue, 02-Aug-2016 18:57:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly; secure

    dim cv : cv = name & "="
    cv = cv & val & "; "
    if inputDate <> "" then
      cv = cv & "expires=" & RFC6265Date(inputDate) & "; "
    end if
    if domain <> "" then
      cv = cv & "domain=" & domain & "; "
    end if
    cv = cv & "path=/; HttpOnly; Secure"

    RFC6265CookieValue = cv

end function
```

To use this, call it like this

```
Response.AddHeader "Set-Cookie", _
                   RFC6265CookieValue( _
                     "cookiename",  _
                     "size=big&flavor=chocolate+chip" _
                     DateAdd("yyyy", 1, Now()), domain), _
                     "example.com"
```

(Classic ASP is like disco. A generation later, it *still* sucks.)