# How can I format date for "expires" value in manual Set-Cookie header in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, header, date-format, setcookie

I'm adding a header for Set-Cookie manually, in VBScript, so that I can include `HttpOnly`.

When I make a `Set-Cookie` header that includes this `expires` value:

```
expires=5/13/2010 9:57:35 AM;
```

Internet Explorer 8 does not set the cookie (FireFox does).  This is what `expires` date formatting look like when set by Response.Cookies("cookieName").Expires:

```
expires=Tue, 01-Jan-1980 08:00:00 GMT;
```

How can I format the first date so that it looks like the second date?

Thanks.

Comment: I am just guessing, but I assume you're talking about server-side VBScript in ASP, not client-side (which would only work in Internet Explorer) right?

Answer (score 0):

VBScript's [FormatDateTime()](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/vbscript/QuickRef/formatdatetime.html) is pretty limited, so that's not an option in your case.  As far as I can see, your only option to format the date as you are asking would be to write a rather long and tedious function to parse out the date, probably with liberal use of the [DatePart()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4kt42529(VS.85).aspx) function...  Personally, I'd just change to Asp.Net rather than bother with it, but likely that's not feasible.

However, [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056654/cookie-httponly-in-classic-asp), which asks the question you're not asking but (I think) you should be, may be more helpful to you.