# Setting httponly flag in IIS 7.5 and classic ASP not working at all

Tags: firefox, cookies, asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Good day,
As per this link:
[Q: How exactly do you configure httpOnly Cookies in ASP Classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296/how-exactly-do-you-configure-httponly-cookies-in-asp-classic) and various other solutions on SO which all basically show the same resolution/coding
we have tried to set the `httponly` flag, both via URL Rewrite module AND entering it manually into both `applicationhost.config` file (for server level) and web.config (for site level) and it simply will not take. We really are at our wits end.

I have Firebug installed to check whether it takes or works and it simply does not. Can anyone possibly think why this would occur? We are using IIS 7.5 on Server 2008 R2 and will be happy to provide any other information required. Please note though that I am not the web designer, I am The IT Administrator and am simply trying to assist my director to find answers.

Comment: You have only linked the question not the specific answer you tried or have you tried all of them? It should work using the [accepted solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/55389/692942) as that is setting a raw header that when returned to the browser should create a cookie with the `HttpOnly` flag set. Going to need to see your code though to have any chance of helping you with this problem.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, we applied answer 10 as it applies specifically to our setup of IIS 7.5 and classic ASP.

Comment: is this really clasic asp? or asp.net?